# Sort a list of objects by parameters in c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have list of users.

I'd like to sort the list by few parameters.

```
            case 0:
                //Date (work) int   for example: 0
                Osu_ve.UserList.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.Index.CompareTo(e2.Index));
                break;

            case 1:
                //Name    (work) string     for example: vectis
                Osu_ve.UserList.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.UData.username.CompareTo(e2.UData.username));
                break;

            case 2:
                //PP      (doesn't work)  string   for example: 14688.76
                Osu_ve.UserList.Sort((e1, e2) => Convert.ToDouble(e2.UData.pp_raw).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(e1.UData.pp_raw)));
                break;
            case 3:
                // Best PP (doesn't work) string   for example: 820.545
                Osu_ve.UserList.Sort((e1, e2) => Convert.ToDouble(e2.UBestScore[0].pp).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(e1.UBestScore[0].pp)));
                break;

            case 4:
                //Rank   (work)   string  for example: 48484
                Osu_ve.UserList.Sort((e1, e2) => Convert.ToDouble(e1.UData.pp_rank).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(e2.UData.pp_rank)));
                break;

            case 5:
                //Country Rank  (work)   string  for example: 54 
                Osu_ve.UserList.Sort((e1, e2) => Convert.ToDouble(e1.UData.pp_country_rank).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(e2.UData.pp_country_rank)));
                break;

            case 6:
                //Acc (doesn't work)   string    for example: 98.5678623
                Osu_ve.UserList.Sort((e1, e2) => Convert.ToDouble(e1.UData.accuracy.Remove(5)).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(e2.UData.accuracy.Remove(5))));
                break;
```

I get this error message: 
Input string was not in a correct format.

Few of them works.
Where is the problem?

Comment: use `Convert.ToDouble(string, IFormatProvider)` overload. Take a look at documentation and/or example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s9ak971(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I get a hunch that you are maybe searching for something like list.OrderBy(x => x.Field1).ThenBy(x => x.Field2) ? p.s. System.Linq is needed for this

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format is pretty self descriptive and is the result of a failed conversion. If you see this in the debugger look at the value of the string that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decimal mark needs to be a dot and not a comma.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that is not totally true. Decimal mark can be hash if you want to. OP should use `ToDouble(string, IFormatProvider)` overload and define comma as decima (or use `Application.CurrentCulture` as IFormatProvider)

Comment: @Ben I am sorry, there is dot. not comma.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")

I am using data from different country.

Thank you all for Your help.